# Как создать исключения при вводе символов?

Tags: c#

В Method_1 на вход подаётся строка, мне нужно исключить почти все существующие символы и оставить только 7 букв и цифры. То есть нужно сделать так что бы в метод можно было писать только определенные буквы, ну там допустим "E" "S" "f". Как это сделать? Я думал может как то с помощью try catch можно? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

```
Console.WriteLine(Method_1(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Comment: regular expressions

Comment: Создай массив разрешенных символов, и когда на вход поступает символ проверяй - есть ли он в массиве с помощью `Contains`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static char[] GoodSimbols = new char[] { '1','2'};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (GoodSimbols.Contains(key.KeyChar))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key.KeyChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```